# Facebook graph SINCE and UNTIL not working with page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have this used to retrieve events of a page

> Microsoft/?fields=events{description,name,start_time}&since=now&until=next
>   year

but it always returns old events

[Direct link for demonstration](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895?method=GET&path=Microsoft%2F%3Ffields%3Devents%7Bdescription%2Cname%2Cstart_time%7D%26since%3Dnow%26until%3Dnext%20year&version=v2.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by doing this:

> Microsoft/events?fields=name,cover,start_time,end_time,place,description&since=now